# Websocket connection error using php and ratchet

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I'm using ratchet to try setup a websocket server for an app. 
I've a problem with the connection, every time I will get this error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://:8080' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

Here is the code that is hosted inside a folder of my shared host. I named the script index.php

Is it possible to fix this issue? Maybe I need to check my php script?

```
<?php
 require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {

protected $clients;

public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
}

public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    //store the new connection
    $this->clients->attach($conn);

    echo "someone connected\n";
}

public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    //send the message to all the other clients except the one who sent.
    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        if ($from !== $client) {
            $client->send($msg);
        }
    }
}

public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $this->clients->detach($conn);
    echo "someone has disconnected";
}

public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
    $conn->close();
}


}

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);

$server->run();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>chatapp</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.3/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    .hidden {
    display: none;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#leave-room {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: right;
}

#user-container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#main-container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#messages {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#msg-container {
    padding: 20px;
}

#msg {
    width: 400px;
}

.user {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.msg {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.time {
    float: right;
    color: #939393;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.details {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
  </style>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="user-container">
            <label for="user">What's your name?</label>
            <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
            <button type="button" id="join-chat">Join Chat</button>
        </div>

        <div id="main-container" class="hidden">
            <button type="button" id="leave-room">Leave</button>
            <div id="messages">

            </div>

            <div id="msg-container">
                <input type="text" id="msg" name="msg">
                <button type="button" id="send-msg">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script id="messages-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each messages}}
        <div class="msg">
            <div class="time">{{time}}</div>
            <div class="details">
                <span class="user">{{user}}</span>: <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </script>

    <script>
      (function(){

    var user;
    var messages = [];

    var messages_template = Handlebars.compile($('#messages-template').html());

    function updateMessages(msg){
        messages.push(msg);
        var messages_html = messages_template({'messages': messages});
        $('#messages').html(messages_html);
        $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
    }

    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://<myserverip>:8080');
    conn.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("Connection established!");
    };

    conn.onmessage = function(e) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
        updateMessages(msg);
    };


    $('#join-chat').click(function(){
        user = $('#user').val();
        $('#user-container').addClass('hidden');
        $('#main-container').removeClass('hidden');

        var msg = {
            'user': user,
            'text': user + ' entered the room',
            'time': moment().format('hh:mm a')
        };

        updateMessages(msg);
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(msg));

        $('#user').val('');
    });


    $('#send-msg').click(function(){
        var text = $('#msg').val();
        var msg = {
            'user': user,
            'text': text,
            'time': moment().format('hh:mm a')
        };
        updateMessages(msg);
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(msg));

        $('#msg').val('');
    });


    $('#leave-room').click(function(){

        var msg = {
            'user': user,
            'text': user + ' has left the room',
            'time': moment().format('hh:mm a')
        };
        updateMessages(msg);
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(msg));

        $('#messages').html('');
        messages = [];

        $('#main-container').addClass('hidden');
        $('#user-container').removeClass('hidden');

        conn.close();
    });

})(jQuery);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is not the right tool for writing WebSocket server and 403 means forbidden.

Comment: @RavinderPayal unfortunately I'm on a shared host, so if I link the server's ip address, It will block the connection and the app will not work. I will give a try using another hosting service (I'm planning to use OVH). any suggestion about a valid hosting service will be accepted

Comment: Ratchet PHP is a great library to create a websocket server. I have personally created my own WSS for a Laravel application instead of using Laravel Websockets package and other technologies. In your question I see you wrote 'ws://:8080' which is strange because it does not have a Domain/IP address, but only the port number. Take a look to the example given in the Ratchet website http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world